# Session hibernate, como obter instancia

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, java

Em toda a documentação do hibernate, e exemplos pela web tem esse exemplo de código, ou um muito parecido, para usar o hibernate.

```
List<Object> list = session.createCriteria(Object.class);
```

Sendo que o session e uma implementação da Interface Session do hibernate, mas como eu consigo essa instacia, já tentei o inject com `@Autowired` do spring(Fremework MVC que estou usando), mas da `java.lang.NullPointerException`.
A pergunta é, como consigo a instancia certa de hibernate.Session?

**EDIT 1**

Oque costumava ser feito era como no trecho de código abaixo:

```
Session session = (Session) this.entityManager.unwrap(Object.class);
```

ou

```
Session session = this.entityManager.unwrap(Object.class);
```

Mas, ao que me parece, isso foi tirado do Hibernate 4.2 ou 5.*, não sei com certeza, oque acontece é que não estou conseguindo mais essa instancia de session, sempre dá null pointer.

**EDIT 2**

Tentei oque o @Javeson Yehudi me sugeriu, que é o seguinte :

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Porem, ainda não funciona, o próprio eclipse não deixou eu usa-lo, pois a classe `AnnotationConfiguration()`, não esta presente nas minhas bibliotecas, porem, como indicado no comentário, apenas `Configuration()` funcionou, só que mudou o erro, agora ele diz que eu não tenho o hibernate.cfg.xml, porque eu estou fazendo essa configuração via código, com o Spring... segue o erro.

```
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dashboardController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'iService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'infoService' defined in file [H:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Administrator\WEB-INF\classes\br\com\finger\service\InfoService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1404)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1394)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'infoService' defined in file [H:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Administrator\WEB-INF\classes\br\com\finger\service\InfoService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:245)
    at br.com.finger.service.InfoService.<clinit>(InfoService.java:40)
    ... 42 more
```

**"Solução"**

Após ler a documentação do hibernate, percebi que a abordagem que estava errada, e que na verdade, não é possível injetar mais essa dependencia Hibernate.SessionFactory, ela foi deprecated para incentivar o uso da especificação do JPA, o que torna as coisas mais facies de dar manutenção mais tarde, apesar de acrescentar um pouco de complexidade, porem como boa pratica é melhor optar pela especifição. Segue o trexo e o link que fala sobre isso.

> Hibernate offers an older, legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API which should be considered deprecated. No feature development will target those APIs. Eventually, Hibernate-specific criteria features will be ported as extensions to the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery. For details on the org.hibernate.Criteria API, see Legacy Hibernate Criteria Queries.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria

Comment: Eu escrevi sobre isso anos atrás, talvez o post lhe seja útil: http://www.simpledev.com.br/spring-hibernate.html

Comment: Bem legal seu post... e exatamente o que eu estou fazendo, só que programáticamente, pois não gosto de xml

Comment: Esse post foi escrito a quase 4 anos atrás :)
De qualquer forma, o principio é o mesmo independente da configuração, você não tem que instanciar a session, simplesmente deixe o Spring fazer isso pra você

Comment: Sim... é oque estou implementando agora.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu estou entendendo o que você quer, então você precisa do SessionFactory para obter uma Session

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory =        new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

http://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-hibernate-session/29215

Agora se você quer com injeção de dependência, você pode encontrar coisas legais [aqui](http://www.guj.com.br/t/cdi-com-tomcat-e-hibernate/203304)

Comment: Essa classe AnnotationConfiguration(), veio de onde? acho que não tenho essa dependencia nas minha bibliotecas...

Comment: Depende das sua versão, tente Configuration no lugar de AnnotationConfiguration

Comment: Editei ai... da uma olhadinha no erro, por favor.

Comment: De fato, pra você usar o Configuration você precisa ter um hibernate.cfg.xml é de lá que ele configura tudo. Como você está usando Spring acho que você tem que usar o autowired, tentar ver esse site http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring

Comment: Oque aconteceu na verdade @JavesonYehudi é que, de acordo com a documentação do hibernate o SessionFactory foi deixado de lado na versão 5.2, para tornar mais usada a especificação do JPA, que é o EntityManager.getCriteriaBuilder(), por isso, eu que estou usando as últimas versões do spring e do hibernate, não consigo injetar.

Comment: @RenatoVieiraDantas de fato eu sei que eles estão tentando dar mais atenção ao JPA. Mas ainda não deixaram de lado a API do hibernate.
Você poderia me dar um exemplo de como você está montando sua classe de configuração? Por que, se você quer usar o EntityManager do JPA o correto era fazer:

`@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistenceUnit")
private EntityManager entityManager;
 
ou
 
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "myPersistenceUnit")
private EntityManagerManager entityManagerManager;`

E pra isso você teria que ter o persistence.xml.

Comment: A classe de configuração é programática, o spring permite que façamos as configurações sem xml... É exatamente isso, com o @PersistenceContext mesmo, estava funcionando perfeitamente assim, até que resolvi mudar, mais agora creio que não sera tão grande a mudança. E vou corrigir o que eu havia dito, de fato, eles não a deixaram de lado, mais foi considerada deprecated.

Comment: Bom, só pra deixar claro: Está correto que o hibernate quer dar mais atenção ao JPA, porém o Session não vai ficar deprecated (eu havia entendido isso). Agora ele irá extender do EntityManager. https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Migration-Guide---5.2

Comment: Hmmmmmmm, então oque vai acontecer e que vamos continuar usando session só que pela especificação e não pela implementação? É isso?

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de utilizar o `@Autowired` tente o `@PersistenceContext`.

Comment: Infelizmente, não funcionou...